# MapView is above all objects in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a mapView in a view in a nib file with the delegate set to file's owner and the outlet is set to IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;

the problem I'm having is that the map is above all other objects. If I add a UIView you don't see it because it is beneath the map.

any idea why this might happen? I haven't had this problem before

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, you need to add the object you created as a subview to your MapView.

For example, here is how you would add an UILabel to the MapView.  Just do this in init

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the label
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 320)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"I'm on top of the Map!";

    // Add the label to the mapView
    [self.mapView addSubview:label];

    // Release the label if you are not using ARC
    [label release];
}
```

Edit:  Keep in mind this concept applies to other objects such as a UISegmentedControl.

Comment: Usually mapview is for exploring map , y would one add controls over it ..doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to add a label or any control over mkmapview , you can instead use its delegate to add an overlay or annotation.
Also if your problem is that mapview is coming all over the screen then set its frame.

If any other case , please explain your problem more clearly.

According to our discussion you can use the function:-

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:yourView];
```

Comment: I wouldn't. that was just an example. I actually have a uiview that animated over the map with a segmented control. either way the map is above everything else for some reason

Comment: you may use [self.view bringSubviewtoFront:subview]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to change the "Z" order in interface builder.  Select the view or other UI element and then look under the Editor menu for Arrange.  There you will find

Send to front

Send to back

Send forward

Send backward